MAUI dynamic UI changes
How to implement custom color changes on content page?
Lets say I've got
<Grid
    x:Name="TopOverlay"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,0.08"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional,HeightProportional"
    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Background}"

And Label
<Label
    Padding="7,0"
    FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"
    FontSize="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModalReaderViewModel}}, Path=FontSize}"
    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
    Text="{Binding .}"
    TextColor="{DynamicResource DarkerTextColor}"

I need to change these Background and DarkerTextColor values as user picks. There will be 3 different option, each will contain different colors for background and label.
Saw some approaches using AppTheme binding, but I need more custom options, maybe in future there appear 4-5 different themes, so how could i create 'myOwn' theme binding sort to say?

Have you tried updating the values in the code-behind or ViewModel? How will the user pick? You can manipulate the values in the code-behind or use bindings, e.g. to the ViewModel.

yes i ended up just changing key values, that came as easiest solution

If you want to define your own theming, consider creating a view model for it, for instance, here I define UserTheme and UserThemes classes and expose it as a singleton through dependency injection. Then my MainPage.xaml can consume and update it:
// UserThemes.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
namespace MauiUserThemes;
public partial class UserTheme : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    Color _backgroundColor = Colors.White;
    [ObservableProperty]
    Color _textColor = Colors.Black;
}
public partial class UserThemes : ObservableObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, UserTheme> Themes { get; } = new()
    {
        ["Light"] = new UserTheme(),
        ["Dark"] = new UserTheme { BackgroundColor = Colors.Black, TextColor = Colors.White },
        ["Blue"] = new UserTheme { BackgroundColor = Colors.Blue, TextColor = Colors.Yellow },
        ["Red"] = new UserTheme { BackgroundColor = Colors.Red, TextColor = Colors.Yellow }
    };
    public List<string> Names => Themes.Keys.ToList();
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Current))]
    string _currentName = "Light";
    public UserTheme Current => Themes[CurrentName];
}

// MauiProgram.cs
//...
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<UserThemes>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
//...

<!--  MainPage.xaml  -->
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiUserThemes.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="mainPage"
    BackgroundColor="{Binding Themes.Current.BackgroundColor, Source={Reference mainPage}}">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{Binding Themes.Current.TextColor, Source={Reference mainPage}}" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{Binding Themes.Current.BackgroundColor, Source={Reference mainPage}}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{Binding Themes.Current.TextColor, Source={Reference mainPage}}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{Binding Themes.Current.TextColor, Source={Reference mainPage}}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Label Text="Select Theme:" />
        <CollectionView Margin="10,0,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Themes.Names, Source={Reference mainPage}}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <Label Text="{Binding Themes.CurrentName, Source={Reference mainPage}, StringFormat='Selected Theme: {0}'}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

// MainPage.xaml.cs
namespace MauiUserThemes;
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public UserThemes Themes { get; }
    public MainPage(UserThemes Themes)
    {
        this.Themes = Themes;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        Themes.CurrentName = btn.Text;
    }
}



MAUI dynamic UI changes
Here's my solution,

First of all, add the ResourceDictionary file you need under the Resources folder, I have created two new ResourceDictionary files here that are DarkTheme and LightTheme.
Introduce these two resource files in the App.xaml file
Add the toggle theme code to the App.xaml.cs file
Add a picker control to the content page, and write the SelectedIndexChanged event function of the picker control in the hidden file

For more information on theme switching, refer to Theme an app.
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/DarkTheme.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/LightTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>


   public void OnThemeSelectionChanged(object sender ,EventArgs e) {
       var picker = (Picker)sender;
       string selectedTheme = (string)picker.SelectedItem;
       ((App)Application.Current).ChangeTheme(selectedTheme);
   }


   public void ChangeTheme(string theme) {
       ResourceDictionary newTheme = null;
       switch (theme) {

           case "Light":
               newTheme = new Test806final.Resources.LightTheme();

               break;
           case "Dark":

               newTheme = new Test806final.Resources.DarkTheme();

               break;
       }
       if (newTheme != null && Application.Current != null) {
           Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

           Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newTheme);

       
       }
   
   
   
   }


